# How to preserve a redis DB when it needs to be regenerated again in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I'm regenerating a `redis` database in a `Sidekiq` job. The things is, it takes a lot of time (2-3 minutes) to finish and the job happens quiet often.

In addition, this redis instance is a master to many slave instances. But the way that I'm regenerating it is basically a flush and then regeneration. When that happens, all the slave instances copy the flushed db. So in that window of 2-3 minutes the data that is shown by the slaves has nothing.

How can I perserve a redis DB when it needs to be regenerated again in Rails so that the slaves won't copy a flushed db?

The code below is the method I currently use:

```
class PlacementsGeneratorJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :high_priority

      def perform(*args)
        redis = Redis.new url: ENV['PLACEMENTS_STORE_URL']
        redis.flushdb
        redis.hset '_default_', 'excluded_ua', Settings.default.excluded_ua.to_json
        Campaign.all.each do |campaign|
          redis.hset '_campaigns_', campaign.id, campaign.settings['search_engines'].to_json
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: Why do you need to flush the data? Why can't you just update the entries?

Comment: @spickermann the code that I present in my question is just a part of the whole process that involves a lot to_json's. easier to regernarate everything than to trace down all changes (i.e. what was deleted or updated)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are flushing because it's easier to regenerate from scratch than try to figure out the transformation. Obviously, it would be best if you could transform via updates, but if you can't, you could just transfer a dump after regenerating it. This will let you keep the database online the whole time, just with a small time of read-only access.

ie:

- Stop replication
- Point live clients (e.g. web server) to slaves in a read-only mode
- Flush and regenerate master (while it's offline)
- Dump master
- Point live clients back to master
- Transfer dump on slaves and restore it
- Turn on replication, slaves will soon catch up to master

Comment: Assuming he uses slaves for reading, the only thing he has to do is break replication temporarily. Also I think redis is smart enough to detect major change in data like that and do a full resync with dump downloading by itself.

Comment: True, breaking replication alone could work, it just depends how much lag there is. If it's a big database and/or slow network and IO, the slaves could be behind for hours or days. (I don't know about the intelligent dump/restore, if that works, then just break replication.)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can you show how to exactly break replication using my code?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I have trouble executing it since redis is in a separate docker container. any other method?

Comment: @Tom: what do you mean, trouble executing? You can't connect to the redis?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can you post an example of the suggest code here? maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @SergioTulentsev this is already the master.. so there's no point to tell it to be slaveof no one.

Comment: @Tom: yeah, you tell that to the slaves.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I can't, they are in different servers.. that's just not doable

Comment: @Tom: if you say so.. Me, I don't see a problem. You know where the slaves are, don't you?